# Angular JS - Number filter - Change colour when negative

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am applying a number filter to the result of a function:

```
<tr class="text-center">
    <th class="text-center">{{monthCategoryTotalPredict = getCategoryMonthTotal(costDirection, month, category, "predict")  | currency:currencySymbol}}</th>
    <th class="text-center">{{monthCategoryTotalActual  = getCategoryMonthTotal(costDirection, month, category, "actual")   | currency:currencySymbol}}</th>
    <th class="text-center">{{calculateSurplus(monthCategoryTotalPredict, monthCategoryTotalActual)  | currency:currencySymbol}}</th>
</tr>
```

Negative numbers are represented like this by default: (£230.00).

My aim is to make them also change colour to red. How can I do this in Angular JS? Can this be part of the filter? Can I override the filter to modify it's default behaviour slightly without a complete rewrite?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use ng-class. You can set the class dynamically based on an expression, like monthCategoryTotalPredict >= 0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to change the color of text in HTML, you'll need to modify it's container element. Since the filter doesn't know about the element, you can either inject one (bad idea), or use a directive instead of a filter.

Putting a function in your code is actually a bad way to handle things. It may have to fire multiple times, and will certainly screw up any kind of sorting you attempt.

```
<th class="text-center" ng-class="{ red: calculateSurplus(monthCategoryTotalPredict, monthCategoryTotalActual) < 0 }">{{calculateSurplus(monthCategoryTotalPredict, monthCategoryTotalActual)  | currency:currencySymbol}}</th>
```

I would honestly perform these calculations ahead of time, so that it looks like this.

```
<th class="text-center" ng-class="{ red: surplus < 0 }">{{surplus | currency:currencySymbol}}</th>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use ng-class to define conditional classes. You can create a css class which presents numbers as red and use it in ng-class attribute.

for example;

```
<td ng-class="{'className': variable < 0}">{{variable}}</td>
```

detailed documentation : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass

Answer (score 4):

You can also use ng-style and add a function to your controller.

for example:

```js
$scope.negativeValue=function(myValue){
  var num = parseInt(myValue);
  
  if(num < 0){
    var css = { 'color':'red' };
    return css;
  }
}
```

```html
<td ng-style="negativeValue(myScopeValue)">{{ myScopeValue | currency }}</td>
```

Comment: thanks, I used this but with ng-class instead of ng-style

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 <th class="text-center" ng-class="{myRedClass: monthCategoryTotalPredict  <0}" >
      {{monthCategoryTotalPredict = ......}}</th>
```

Then add a css class rule to change color

Answer (score 0):

That's how it did it in my app.

All of the solutions above would recalculate the value, which could be inefficient, if it is resulted by a function.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", myCtrl)
  .directive("colorUp", colorUp)

function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.num1 = 1
  $scope.num2 = -1
  $scope.num3 = 0
}

function colorUp() {
 return {
  restrict: "A",
  link: linkFunc
 }

 function linkFunc (scope, element, attributes) {
  //adding an event handler to see elements' value changes
  element.on("DOMSubtreeModified", onValChange)

  function onValChange () {
   var eleVal = deComma(element.text())
   var color  = (eleVal > 0) ? "green": (eleVal < 0) ? "red": ""
   element.attr("class", "ng-binding " + color)
  }
  
  function deComma(text) { 
    return (text ? (text+"").replace(/,/g, "") : "")
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
    .red {color: red;}
    .green {color: green;}
     input { width : 50px;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h3>Reusable Custom directive for coloring nums.</h3>
    <input type="number" ng-model="num1" placeholder="Enter first number here!!">
    <label color-up>{{num1 | number:2}}</label>
    <br>
    <input type="number" ng-model="num2" placeholder="Enter second number here!!">
    <label color-up>{{num2 | number:2}}</label>
    <br>
    <input type="number" ng-model="num3" placeholder="Enter second number here!!">
    <label color-up>{{num3 | number:2}}</label>
  </body>

</html>
```

here is a plunker link:-
http://plnkr.co/edit/X42mE9LpagGRrasOckqQ?p=preview

Hope it helps!!